# Google Analytics Code not tracking my Blog hits

Tags: google-analytics

I have installed Google Analytics Code on [my blog](http://mink7.com/blog) but i am not able to register any hits on my blog for a while now. The code works perfect on my Website at http://mink7.com

Answer (score 1):

The only issue I see currently: On your site, you have it in the head, [which is where it is now supposed to be](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/asyncTracking). In your blog you have it just above the closing body tag.